# Can not Call function from one js to second function

Tags: javascript, angular

I bought metronic admin template and trying to use it in angular 2 but i have error with two JS files: `app.js` and `layout.js`.

`app.js` content:

```
var test = function () {
    /* ... */
    return {
        init: function(){ /* ... */ },

        getResponsiveBreakpoint: function(size) {
            // bootstrap responsive breakpoints
            var sizes = {
                'xs': 480,     // extra small
                'sm': 768,     // small
                'md': 992,     // medium
                'lg': 1200     // large
            };

            return sizes[size] ? sizes[size] : 0;
        }
    }
}();

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    test.init(); // init metronic core componets
});
```

`layout.js` content:

```
var Layout = function () {
    var resBreakpointMd = test.getResponsiveBreakpoint('md');
    /* ... */

    return {
        init: function() { /* ... */ }
    }
}();

$(document).ready(function() {
    Layout.init(); // init metronic core componets
});
```

`layout.js` returns this error:

> test.getResponsiveBreakpoint is not a function

But if I write `test.getResponsiveBreakpoint('md');` outside of layout function, it works.

```
console.log(test.getResponsiveBreakpoint('md'));
var Layout = function() {/* ... */}
```

Comment: If that console.log worked, your browser is trolling you :v

Comment: Of course it will fail, because `test.getResponsiveBreakpoint` is not a function yet. It will not like this with current Layout structure.

Comment: How are you loading the js files?

Comment: first i call app.js and then layout.js

yeap console.log is working,its returning me: 992

Answer (score 0):

Remove `self invoking` for the function  `Layout`.
i.e,
Instead of this

```
var Layout = function () {
    ...
    //Your Code...
}();
```

Use this,

```
var Layout = function () {
    ...
    //Your Code...
};
```

UPDATE :

app.js

```
var test = function () {

        return {
                init:function(){
                    return  100;
                },

            getResponsiveBreakpoint: function (size) {
            var sizes = {
            'xs': 480,     // extra small
            'sm': 768,     // small
            'md': 992,     // medium
            'lg': 1200     // large
        };

            return sizes[size] ? sizes[size] : 0;
        }
    }
}();
```

layout.js

```
var Layout = function () {
    var resBreakpointMd = test.getResponsiveBreakpoint('xs');
    return{
        init:function(){
            return resBreakpointMd;
        }
        }    
};

$(document).ready(function() { 
    console.log(Layout().init());
});
```

Comment: yes i know,app.js is loading first but error still exist

Comment: i change it and the call it in 

`$(document).ready(function() {   
      Layout(); 
    });`

but same error

Comment: Did you remove self invoking for `test` function as-well ? If so, don't remove for `test` function.

Comment: did you use it in angular 2? yeap it works with out angular 2 cli?

i am using this files in .net core and its works,also i tested in plunker and its work also but not in angular 2 cli project